# How to make the indicator work only on a formed candle?

Tags: pine-script

I found such an indicator on Pine Script on the Internet.
I have a question: this indicator is recalculated every time the candle is updated (that is, when the candle has not yet formed) is it possible to do something so that the indicator is recalculated only when the candle has formed? I ask for help in this matter, since I myself do not know Pine Script very well

```
//@version=4
study("Chandelier Exit", shorttitle="CE", overlay=true)

length = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=22)
mult = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)
showLabels = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Labels ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
useClose = input(title="Use Close Price for Extremums ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
highlightState = input(title="Highlight State ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

atr = mult * atr(length) // array
longStop = (useClose ? highest(close, length) : highest(length)) - atr // array
longStopPrev = nz(longStop[1], longStop) // array prev or last 
longStop := close[1] > longStopPrev ? max(longStop, longStopPrev) : longStop
 
 
shortStop = (useClose ? lowest(close, length) : lowest(length)) + atr
shortStopPrev = nz(shortStop[1], shortStop)
shortStop := close[1] < shortStopPrev ? min(shortStop, shortStopPrev) : shortStop
 
var int dir = 1
dir := close > shortStopPrev ? 1 : close < longStopPrev ? -1 : dir
 
var color longColor = color.green
var color shortColor = color.red
 
longStopPlot = plot(dir == 1 ? longStop : na, title="Long Stop", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=longColor)
buySignal = dir == 1 and dir[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal ? longStop : na, title="Long Stop Start", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=longColor, transp=0)
plotshape(buySignal and showLabels ? longStop : na, title="Buy Label", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=longColor, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
 
shortStopPlot = plot(dir == 1 ? na : shortStop, title="Short Stop", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=shortColor)
sellSignal = dir == -1 and dir[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal ? shortStop : na, title="Short Stop Start", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=shortColor, transp=0)
plotshape(sellSignal and showLabels ? shortStop : na, title="Sell Label", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=shortColor, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)
 
midPricePlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, display=display.none, editable=false)
 
longFillColor = highlightState ? (dir == 1 ? longColor : na) : na
shortFillColor = highlightState ? (dir == -1 ? shortColor : na) : na
fill(midPricePlot, longStopPlot, title="Long State Filling", color=longFillColor)
fill(midPricePlot, shortStopPlot, title="Short State Filling", color=shortFillColor)
 
changeCond = dir != dir[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title="Alert: CE Direction Change", message="Chandelier Exit has changed direction!")
alertcondition(buySignal, title="Alert: CE Buy", message="Chandelier Exit Buy!")
alertcondition(sellSignal, title="Alert: CE Sell", message="Chandelier Exit Sell!")
 
 
 
if buySignal
    alert("###BUY###", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if sellSignal
    alert("###SELL###", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `and barstate.isconfirmed` to your buy and sell conditions should do the trick.

Buy condition

```
buySignal = dir == 1 and dir[1] == -1 and barstate.isconfirmed
```

Sell Condition

```
sellSignal = dir == -1 and dir[1] == 1 and barstate.isconfirmed
```

Comment: Strange for some reason it still doesn't work as expected: I added what you wrote, and also added `if buySignal and barstate.isconfirmed
    alert("###BUY###", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
if sellSignal and barstate.isconfirmed
    alert("###SELL###", alert.freq_once_per_bar)` but alerts still appear when a candle is formed, I can see it because an alert appears although there is no signal on the chart (or it has just disappeared)